# how to click element when the id,class name is not unique using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to click this daily tasks link but here id and class name is not unique,
My DOM element is:

[image]

I tried :

```
#My Restaurant Configuration MENU
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn name-container x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon']//span[contains(text()='My Restaurant Configuration']").click()
  print("second sub link")
```

getting following error:

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@class='x-btn name-container x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon']//span[contains(text()='My Restaurant Configuration'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@class='x-btn name-container x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon']//span[contains(text()='Daily Tasks']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Daily Tasks')]"
```

try also this option

```
driver.find_element_by_id("button-1184-btnInnerEl")
```

also try installing an extension for chrome or opera called cropath, it is very useful when you are still learning

Comment: As i mentioned id and class name is not unique so i couldnot use find_element_by_id. And this xpath also not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='x-btn name-container x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon']//span[contains(text(), 'Daily Tasks')]").click()
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[@class='x-btn name-container x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon']//span/text()[contains(.,'Daily Tasks')]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: @DivyaMani - See edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Please i updated my question with your findings.Please correct my code

Comment: @DivyaMani Don't know what to say; it's definitely a valid xpath expression.